# How to ignore the system default Locale to retrieve resourceBundle

Tags: java, localization, resourcebundle

I am localizing a web application using a `java.util.ResourceBundle` class and property files.

I have two locales, fr_FR and en_US, and I want to use en_US as the default, so I wrote the following files :

- `messages_fr_FR.properties` with fr_FR messages
- `messages.properties` with en_US messages

My problem is that the [ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) method fall back `Locale.getDefault()` before using the default property file, which means if the JVM Locale is set to fr_FR, 
`ResourceBundle.getBundle("name", new Locale("en", "US"))` returns the fr_FR bundle.

I could rename the `messages.properties` file, but this could returns a MissingResourceException with other desired and default locales.

How can I ignore the System Locale, without duplicating the property file or calling `Locale.setDefault` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that by using a custom `ResourceBundle.Control`, either by overloading the `getFallbackLocale`explicitly, or by using :

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("name", new Locale("en", "US"), ResourceBundle.Control.getNoFallbackControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_PROPERTIES))
```

Answer (score -1):

The bundle you are looking for is called the `baseBundle`, and it can be obtained 
with ease using Locale.ROOT as the Locale. Like this:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundle name",Locale.ROOT)
```