# How to configure ResourceBundle "no fallback control" in Java 9

Tags: internationalization, java-9, resourcebundle, java-10

As answered in [How to ignore the system default Locale to retrieve resourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422727/how-to-ignore-the-system-default-locale-to-retrieve-resourcebundle/26461551#26461551) you can configure in Java 8 or older to not fallback to default locale via:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResources",
  new Locale("en", "US"),
  ResourceBundle.Control.getNoFallbackControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_PROPERTIES))
```

In Java 9, [ResourceBundle.Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) usage throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when used in Named Modules: `ResourceBundle.Control` is **not** supported in named modules.

How do I implement/configure a custom "MyResourcesProvider[Impl]" to achieve the same behaviour as the `ResourceBundle.Control.getNoFallbackControl` provided?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implements a `java.util.spi.ResourceBundleProvider` and register it as service for the base name.

The getBundle(String, Locale) should return `null` if no resource is available.

The problem is that you need to register for every bundle base name its own provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it directly over:

```
Control.newBundle( baseName, locale, "java.properties", loader, false );
```

But then you need to implements the caching self.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using UTF8, instead of `ISO-8859-1`? Because Java 8 and before used it for `ResourceBundle` and properties files.

See: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/226

Comment: Encoding doesn't matter here: an `UnsupportedOperationException` is the issue.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer - could you please tell me what was wrong with it? Or did you just downvoted it because you thought it wasn't a solution for @Sormuras problem?

Comment: @Sormuras For example, if you invoke `URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");`, you can get `UnsupportedOperationException` for unsupported encoding.

Comment: You are making it even worse. `UnsupportedEncodingException` it is -- but what has it do with my question? Right. Nothing.
I downvoted it because "the answer is not useful".

Comment: It's not `UnsupportedEncodingException`, it's `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I thought of a correlation between you, saying that it stopped working after migrating to Java 9 and finding out a source that says properties file encoding changed in Java 9 (from here http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/226) and because I remembered that using wrong encodings often resulted in `UnsupportedOperationException`.